# Quick reset to reinstate network connection on W10?

Tags: windows, networking, connection, adapter, powerline-networking

For the time being I am unfortunate enough to depend on a powerline adapter for the network connection to my desktop PC. It is a basic TP-Link model and works fine when it works fine... but I've been getting quite a few drop-outs at random (and sometimes highly inconvenient) moments. No obvious cause such as other devices in use at the time.

The problem is nearly always resolved by unplugging the LAN cable, leaving it a few seconds and plugging back in. What I'm wondering is whether there is such a thing as a quick adapter reset or some other such software routine that I can perform on Windows 10 that would achieve the same thing, without having to crawl under the desk every time?! Obviously I'd rather avoid anything convoluted and preferably also avoid losing existing settings (although I can't recall what I may have had to change from the defaults, if anything).

Hope this makes sense - it just feels like there should be some way of telling Windows or the NIC or whatever to 'just try that connection again', in the same way that re-plugging the LAN cable seems to do.

T.I.A.

Comment: Run TCP/IP Reset.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: Thank you @John, I'll give that a go next time it drops out (I suspect I won't be waiting long...).